# How do I call a function on a PyQt4 button click?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, dbus

I'm writing a spotify controller for linux and for the GUI I'm using 
PyQt4. I've been trying to solve this for a while but I can't.

heres my code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

import dbus
import pygtk
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("Hello world")

player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify', '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
properties_manager = dbus.Interface(player, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')

curr_volume = properties_manager.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Metadata')


info = [curr_volume["xesam:title"], curr_volume["xesam:albumArtist"], curr_volume["xesam:title"], 'd']

def nextNotify():
    nextNotify=Notify.Notification.new("Skipped Song:", "Click Previous To Go Back: BROKEN", "dialog-information")
    nextNotify.show()

def previousNotify():
    previousNotify=Notify.Notification.new(" Song:", "Click Next To Play Next Song: ", "dialog-information")
    previousNotify.show()

def pauseNotify():
    pauseNotify=Notify.Notification.new(" Paused Song:", "Click Play To Continue Listening ", "dialog-information")
    pauseNotify.show()

def playNotify():
    playNotify=Notify.Notification.new(" Playing Song", "Click Pause To Pause Song: ", "dialog-information")
    playNotify.show()

def infoNotify():
    infoNotify=Notify.Notification.new(" Song info:", "Title: " + info[0] + " - " + info[1][0], "dialog-information")
    infoNotify.show()



from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):



        #Button clicked functions
        def on_button1_clicked():
            player.Next(dbus_interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
            nextNotify()

        def on_button2_clicked():
            player.Previous(dbus_interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
            previousNotify()

        def on_button3_clicked():
            player.Play(dbus_interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
            playNotify()

        def on_button4_clicked():
            player.Pause(dbus_interface='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
            pauseNotify()

        def on_button5_clicked():
            infoNotify()

        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(229, 364)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 242, 85, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 276, 85, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 208, 85, 28))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 174, 85, 28))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 310, 85, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 161, 121))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("about:blank")))
        self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
        self.webView.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        #Button clicked actions

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), on_button1_clicked())



        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pause", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Previous", None))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "info", None))

from PyQt4 import QtWebKit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And my problem is this line.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), on_button1_clicked())
```

And I get this error:

```
line 115, in setupUi
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), on_button1_clicked())
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 2 has unexpected type 'bytes'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), on_button1_clicked) try this and move the on_button1_clicked() function defined inside the setupUi(self, MainWindow) outside as a independent function of your UI_MainWindow class.

Comment: Also prefer to use modern syntax for signals and slots in pyqt.                      For example self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.on_button1_clicked)

Comment: your ui file and the logic for processing the events, signals and slots of your ui should be seperate...so that if you modify your ui file....the changes dont get lost...